# how to solve this expression by function DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

how to resolve this expression in mathemtica wolfram by method DSolve

y'=xy^2

and

y'=yx^2

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post what you've tried with `DSolve[]`?

Comment: DSovle[y'[x]= xy^2[x], y[x]. x]

Comment: And DSolve[y'[x] == y (x^2)[x], y[x], x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have number of syntax errors. You really need to first learn the basic syntax. There are many examples in the help. If you have used Wolfram Alpha before, then Mathematica syntax is more strict. Can't use any syntax in Mathematica like with Wolfram Alpha. Wolfram alpha uses A.I. to try to guess what you meant. No such thing in Wolfram Mathematica.

```
 DSolve[y'[x]==x y[x]^2,y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 DSolve[y'[x]==y[x] x^2,y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]